# How to send local notifications to user weekdays with different texts with Swift

Tags: swift, date, notifications, nsnotificationcenter, usernotifications

want to send notification to the users in all days according to day name for example if today is Wednesday and hour is 4 pm send notification with "Today is Wednesday hello do something" and after that day I mean Thursday when clock is 4pm send notification like "hello its Thursday do your sport" and so on can you help me

```
 public struct NotificationManager {
    let notificationCenter = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    static let sharedInstance = NotificationManager()
    
   private func checkRequestAuthorization(completion: @escaping(Bool) -> Void) -> () {
        let options: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .sound,]
        notificationCenter.requestAuthorization(options: options) {
            (didAllow, error) in
            completion(didAllow)
        }
    }
    
    func setLocalNotifications() {
        checkRequestAuthorization { isAllowed in
            if isAllowed {
                let credentials = getNotificationsCredentials()
                addNotificationRequest(title: Localizables.InformationTitles.notificationTitle, body: Localizables.InformationTexts.notificationBody, notifications: credentials)
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func getNotificationsCredentials() -> [CustomNotification] {
        return [ CustomNotification(hours: [8,16], title: ["Smiling Sunday", "Self Sunday"], body: ["What makes you smile?", "Let’s take some time to draw today!"]),
                 CustomNotification(hours: [16], title: ["Mindful Monday"], body: ["Let’s nn today!"]),
                 CustomNotification(hours: [16], title: ["Thoughtful Tuesday"], body: ["Come and play!"]),
                 CustomNotification(hours: [16], title: ["Wishful Wednesday"], body: ["Let’s make a wish today!"]),
                 CustomNotification(hours: [16], title: ["Thankful Thursday"], body: ["What are you thankful for today?"]),
                 CustomNotification(hours: [16], title: ["Feeling Friday"], body: ["Let’s explore our feelings together!"]),
                 CustomNotification(hours: [8,16], title: ["Super Saturday", "Singing Saturday"], body: ["What are you super excited for today?", "Let’s dance and sing together!"]),
        ]
    }
    
   private func addNotificationRequest(title: String, body: String, notifications: [CustomNotification]) {
        notificationCenter.removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()
        let selectedNotification = notifications[Date().dayNumberOfWeek()!-1]
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = title
        content.body = body
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default
        let gregorian = Calendar(identifier: Calendar.Identifier.gregorian)
        let now = Date()
        var components = gregorian.dateComponents(in: .autoupdatingCurrent, from: now)
        let hours = [14,18]
        for hour in hours {
            components.timeZone = TimeZone.current
            components.hour = hour
            components.minute = 28
            components.second = 00
            let date = gregorian.date(from: components);
            let formatter = DateFormatter();
            formatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm";
            let dailyTrigger = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: date!);
            let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dailyTrigger, repeats: true);
            let identifier = UUID().uuidString
            let reguest = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: identifier, content: content, trigger: trigger)
            notificationCenter.add(reguest) { err in
                print("notification fired")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i have a notification manager that full fill all your need for 5$ only

Comment: that are easy to use and can fire more than 62 notification a day ios limit notification 62 / day

Answer (score 0):

i found it i just created all my notification and with for loop i request for all of them and datetimertriger did the job

```
public struct NotificationManager {
    let notificationCenter = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    static let sharedInstance = NotificationManager()
    
   private func checkRequestAuthorization(completion: @escaping(Bool) -> Void) -> () {
        let options: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .sound,]
        notificationCenter.requestAuthorization(options: options) {
            (didAllow, error) in
            completion(didAllow)
        }
    }
    
    func setLocalNotifications() {
        checkRequestAuthorization { isAllowed in
            if isAllowed {
                let credentials = getNotificationsCredentials()
                addNotificationRequest(title: Localizables.InformationTitles.notificationTitle, body: Localizables.InformationTexts.notificationBody, notifications: credentials)
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func getNotificationsCredentials() -> [CustomNotification] {
        return [
            CustomNotification(hours: 8, title: "Smiling Sunday", body: "What makes you smile?", weekDay: 1),
            CustomNotification(hours: 16, title: "Self Sunday", body: "Let’s take some time to draw today!", weekDay: 1),
            CustomNotification(hours: 16, title: "Mindful Monday", body: "Let’s tinker today!",weekDay: 2),
            CustomNotification(hours: 16, title: "Thoughtful Tuesday", body: "Come and play!",weekDay: 3),
            CustomNotification(hours: 16, title: "Wishful Wednesday", body: "Let’s make a wish today!",weekDay: 4),
            CustomNotification(hours: 16, title: "Thankful Thursday", body: "What are you thankful for today?",weekDay: 5),
            CustomNotification(hours: 16, title: "Feeling Friday,", body: "Let’s explore our feelings together!",weekDay: 6),
            CustomNotification(hours: 8, title: "Super Saturday", body: "What are you super excited for today?",weekDay: 7),
            CustomNotification(hours: 16, title: "Singing Saturday,", body: "Let’s dance and sing together!",weekDay: 7),
        ]
    }
    
    private func addNotificationRequest(title: String, body: String, notifications: [CustomNotification]) {
        notificationCenter.removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()
       // let gregorian = Calendar(identifier: Calendar.Identifier.gregorian)
      //  let now = Date()
        for notification in notifications {
            let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
            content.title = notification.title
            content.body = notification.body
            content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default
            var dateComponents = DateComponents()
            dateComponents.timeZone = TimeZone.current
            dateComponents.hour = notification.hours
            dateComponents.minute = 10
            dateComponents.second = 00
            dateComponents.weekday = notification.weekDay
            //let date = gregorian.date(from: dateComponents);
            let notificationTrigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: true)

//            let formatter = DateFormatter();
//            formatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm";
//            let dailyTrigger = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: date!);
//            let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dailyTrigger, repeats: true);
            let identifier = UUID().uuidString
            let reguest = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: identifier, content: content, trigger: notificationTrigger)
            notificationCenter.add(reguest) { err in
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```